# In which order should we apply primary key, foreign key constraints and create index if the Oracle table has data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

1.In which order should we apply primary key, foreign key constraints and create index if the Oracle table has millions of data and does not have prior constraints?

2.Can we use 'NOLOGGING PARALLEL' while applying primary key and  foreign key constraints like we do while applying(creating) indexes? Or any other method so that primary key and  foreign key constraints could be applied faster?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I'll use *bullets* so that it is easier to read, as it is easy to get lost in long sentences.

My thoughts on the subject; see if anything of this helps.

---

Well,

- as you can't create a foreign key constraint if column(s) it references aren't part of primary or unique key
- you'll obviously first have to create primary key constraints
- and then foreign key constraints

When you

- create a primary key constraint,
- Oracle automatically creates index that supports it, unless there's already an index you can use (with the `USING INDEX` clause)
- which means that you can "skip" some indexes (those for primary key constraints as they'll already exist) and *virtually* save some time
- and create "other" indexes

On the other hand,

- if you first create *unique* index on *future* primary key columns and
- later add primary key constraint with the `USING INDEX` clause, Oracle will "skip" check for possible duplicate values because unique index won't allow them

The same goes for

- `NOT NULL` constraint on *future* primary key columns; primary key doesn't allow `NULL`s so - if a column already *is* `NOT NULL`, enforcing primary key constraint can skip `NULL` check as well

I don't know

- which columns you'll additionally index, but - as you're on Oracle 11g -
- don't forget to index all foreign key constraint columns
- because you might encounter *unexpected* table locks if you

  - update primary key column in parent table, or
  - delete parent record

---

Can you do it with no logging and in parallel? Yes:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create unique index ui1_test_id on test (id) nologging parallel 20;

Index created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id) using index ui1_test_id nologging parallel 20;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

But you'll probably want to change the index and table back to `NOPARALLEL` and `LOGGING` when the initial creation is done.

```
SQL> alter index ui1_test_id noparallel;

Index altered.

SQL> alter table test logging noparallel;

Table altered.
```